# Can I share a MySQL database among multiple users exclusively?

Tags: mysql, permissions

This can be a silly/invalid question but I am going to ask it anyway. I want to setup a testing environment where many developers can run their functional test against a single common database.

Now, how can I ensure that the developers don't mess up with the test data when they run their test simultaneously? Is there a way to partition the db based on the user accessing it? Partitioning may be the wrong word here but I think you get what I mean.

Comment: In MySQL what they call a "database" [is in fact a schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html), that is, a namespace for tables and such. All "databases"/schemas are part of a single physical database instance, and you should indeed set up _separate_ "databases"/schemas for each developer.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a `DATABASE` of the shared data.  `GRANT` users only `SELECT` permissions.  (And maybe a few other non-destructive privs.)

Set up another `DATABASE` for each user.  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES TO user1_db.* ON 'user1'@...;`

Then set up a way to initialize their db with a copy of the readonly copy.  Perhaps it could be a Stored Proc.  Or maybe a shell script.

Another approach is to set up a Docker instances, one per user.  Again, there needs to be a script to initialize their data.

**OR...**

If each dev does not need to mess with the existing data, consider having a single `DATABASE` with permissions `GRANTed` at the `TABLE` level.

Comment: So you're saying to create a db per developer? If yes, is there any way to accomplish this with a single db?

Comment: I added to my Answer.